# Using row_number with a view?

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I want to use `row_number` with a view, so that each row is assigned a new sequential id

```
CREATE VIEW feed AS 
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id, title FROM books 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, title FROM movies) alias
ORDER BY id
```

I've tried:

```
CREATE VIEW feed AS 
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER FROM (
SELECT id, title FROM books 
UNION ALL
SELECT id, title FROM movies) alias
ORDER BY id
```

But no luck, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OVER` keyword must be followed by `()`:

```
CREATE VIEW feed AS
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM (
SELECT id, title FROM books
UNION ALL
SELECT id, title FROM movies) alias;
```

It's okay for the parentheses to be empty if you have no PARTITION or ORDER BY, but in this case I'd put the ORDER BY inside, so you are sure it applies to the ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Thanks, how can I name the new id column created? e.g. `view_id`

Comment: Follow the column with `AS` and then an alias name. Same as defining any other column alias.